# sap.ui.core library is not available at compile time using open UI5 with eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5

I am new to OPEN UI5, I have done the setup of importing Open UI5 in eclipse keepler version.

I can execute sample application inside my Javascript views but if I try using sap.ui.core library then I am unable to see the options/Classes inside it but I am able to see commons package and its content.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <!-- Bootstrap Script to load Open UI5 at Runtime (Including library and Themes)-->

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>

    <!-- Application Script (specific to the application ) -->  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            sap.ui.localResources("TelephoneDirectory");
            var view = sap.ui.view({id : "loginPage", 
                                    viewName : "TelephoneDirectory.LoginPage", 
                                    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
            view.placeAt("content");
        </script>


    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing some bootstrap files ?

I want that the sap.ui.core functions will be visible in eclipse when I press ctrl+space.

Comment: Add `sap.ui.core` at `data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3"`

Comment: @NareshKumarDevalapally I already tried that , my core components are working fine if i add the code sap.ui.core.(any component) but i am still unable to see the options from dropdown like if i want to list all the core components and classes.